# Vue.js Node.js MySQL Heroku 405 Not Allowed nginx

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, heroku

I created an application for authorization and registration of users on Vue + Node.js + MySQL, everything works fine locally, then I deploy the application on heroku, connect ClearDB MySQL (created a database, connected to node.js), frontend app works well, but when I want to log in, I get the error 405 Not Allowed nginx, what do I need to do to make my app work normally?  When I run the app using the "heroku local web" command, everything works too [405 Not Allowed nginx heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK3DL.png), [Network Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyovJ.png)

Comment: https://github.com/VyacheslavGL/vue-nodejs-mysql-nginx-heroku-web

Comment: Could you update the question to add the relevant code pieces? It would help if you showed the HTML and the Vue code as well as the node.js endpoint code that you expect to process the POST request.